# Open a Popup from a Scrollviewer

Tags: c#, xaml, popup, windows-runtime, scrollview

I'm making a WinRT application using XAML and I have a control that has a TextBox and a Popup that opens under it when the TextBox get focus.
The Width of the Popup is the same as the Width of the TextBox. This works fine but if I put my control in a ScrollViewer and zoom in the size of the popup doesn't change. I would like to achieve something similar to the standard ComboBox which changes the size of its Popup when it is nested in a ScrollViewer. What should I do?

I know that the popup must be part of the VisualTree but I'm not quite sure how to add it without changing the existing layout.
Thank you

Comment: What is the parent of your popup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have the popup be parented in the `TextBox` you can either modify the template of the `TextBox` and put it in there (you could subclass `TextBox` to both add support for your dropdown logic and change the default template at the same time) or simply find the root `Grid` of the `TextBox` using `VisualTreeHelper`. By default `TextBox` has a `Grid` at its root, so you could get that and add the `Popup` to its `Children`.

Comment: The parent of my Popup is a Grid. The TextBox and the Popup are in the same Grid. The problem here is that when I open the Popup it is clipped by the size of the Grid. Should I change the parent of the Popup when it is opened it this case?

Comment: Ok, I found the problem. When the popup has fixed width and height it stays clipped by the containing Grid. I removed the fixed sized and now it works fine.